# How to check if the image is captured in activity intent in Android using Java

Tags: java, android, android-camera-intent

I am coding an Android app using Java. I have a function to use an activity intent to capture a image file. I want how to programmatically check if the image file is captured or not.

My function:

```
private void launchTakeImageWithCameraIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    File imageFile = createTemporaryWritableImageFile();
    path = imageFile.getPath();

    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    grantUriPermissions(intent, imageUri);

    try {
      activity.startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_ID);  // <-- how to check if the image file is captured or not?
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
      try {
        if (!imageFile.delete()) {
          throw new RuntimeException("failed to delete image file.");
        }
      } catch (SecurityException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
      }
      result.error(
          "no_available_activity",
          "no camera available for taking picture.",
          null
      );
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `createTemporaryWritableImageFile();` It is unclear what you are doing here. You should not create an empty file already. You only need a File instance that points to a non existing file. The file will then be created by the camera app if the user confirms.

Comment: `Uri.fromFile(imageFile);` Uri.fromFile is not usable since Android 7. What are you programming for?

Comment: `grantUriPermissions(intent, imageUri);` That does not make sense. You better add a WRITE flag.

Comment: `How to check if the image is captured in activity intent` You mean: How can i check if the camera app created and wrote a file?

Comment: Further: In OnActivityResult you can check the result parameter which tells you if the picture is take/file created.

Answer (score 1):

In this onActivityResult method, you can check the result code to determine whether the capture was successful

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_ID) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Image captured successfully
        // You can now check if the image file exists at the specified path
        File imageFile = new File(path);
        if (imageFile.exists()) {
            // Image file exists
            // You can proceed with further actions
        } else {
            // Image file doesn't exist
            // Handle this case as needed
        }
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // User canceled the capture
        // Handle this case if needed
    } else {
        // Capture failed or was not successful
        // Handle this case if needed
    }
}
```

}